# No errors but getting a 404

Tags: php, laravel, routes, http-status-code-404

i'm developing a listing directory web application.

Here, i would like a user (Pre-set as revisor) to be able to approve or reject the ads posted from the guests.

I've done the following in the revisor dashboard :

```html
<x-layout>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img src=" https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{$ad->title}}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{$ad->description}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{$ad->category->name}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{$ad->user->name}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{$ad->created_at->format('d/m/Y')}}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{{$ad->price}},00 €</p>
                <a href="{{route('ad.detail' , compact('ad'))}}" class="btn btn-primary">Vai al dettaglio!</a>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between mt-3">
                    <form action="post" action="{{route('revisor.accept', $ad->id)}}">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon></button>
                    </form>
                    <form action="post" action="{{route('revisor.reject', $ad->id)}}">
                        @csrf
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   
</x-layout>
```

Also, i've done the following in my `RevisorController` :

```js
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Ad;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\RevisorController;

class RevisorController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){

        $this->middleware('auth.revisor');
    }

    public function revisor(){
       $ad=Ad::where('is_accepted',null)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
       return view('revisor', compact('ad'));
        
    }

    public function setAccepted($id,$value){
        $ad=Ad::find($id);
       $ad->is_accepted=$value;
       $ad->save();
       return redirect(route('revisor'));
    
    }
    public function accept(){
      return $this->setAccepted($id,true);
    }
    public function reject(){
        return $this->setAccepted($id,false);
    }
}
```

In my `Routes` i've defined two post routes as following :

```html
Route::post('/revisor/ad/{id}/accept',[RevisorController::class,'accept'])->name('revisor.accept');
Route::post('/revisor/ad/{id}/reject',[RevisorController::class,'reject'])->name('revisor.reject');
```

As above, everything seems to be correct in my eyes but i don't understand why when i try to reject or accept an Ad it returns a '404 page not found'.

I noticed that the URL of the request remain stuck like this:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/post?_token=Rm5CeNOjKUoOsynv4Nkh0dpxqIJ4AE6OR8Ozxo25

Then, i've tried to put several `dd()` into my controller's function but it seems that the system is not going through any of the function into the `RevisorController`.

Also i've tried to search any kind of answer to the matter but did not find any suitable.

Is there anybody that can help me with these matter?

Comment: _"I noticed that the URL of the request remain stuck like this:"_ Stuck how/when/where?

Comment: @Magnus when i try to accept/reject the Ad

Comment: @Dennis if i remove the middleware than this page would be accesible from users that are not revisor, right?

Comment: `action="post"` ... well there you go

Comment: @lagbox ok, that is true, i'm totaly done for today...i was getting crazy

Comment: I've voted to close it as a typo-question.

Answer (score 0):

You access by `GET` method, not `POST`. You have an error here :

```
action="post"
```

```
<form action="post" action="{{route('revisor.accept', $ad->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</form>
<form action="post" action="{{route('revisor.reject', $ad->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</form>
```

Should :

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('revisor.accept', $ad->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</form>
<form method="post" action="{{route('revisor.reject', $ad->id)}}">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</form>
```